# Cipher to generate URL safe ciphertext without encoding

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt small serialized data structures (~256 bytes) so I can pass them around (especially in  URLs) safely. My current approach is to use a symmetric block cipher, and then to base 64 encode, then URL encode the cipher text. This yields an encoded cipher text that is (unsurprisingly) quite a bit longer than the original data structure. The length of these encoded ciphers is a bit of a usability problem; ideally I'd like the cipher text to be around the same length as the input text.

Is there a block cipher that can be configured to constrain the values of the output bytes to be in the URL-safe range? I assume there would be a security trade-off involved if there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a given key K, a cipher has to produce a different ciphertext for each plaintext.  If your message space is 256 bytes, the cipher has to be able to produce at least 256^256 different messages.  This will require at least 256 bytes, and any reduction in the size of the output alphabet requires longer messages.

As you've seen, you can do some encoding afterward to avoid certain output symbols, at the cost of increased length.  Furthermore, you would pay the same cost if the encoding were part of the encryption algorithm proper.  That's why this isn't a feature of any encryption algorithm.

As others have mentioned, the only real answer is to reduce the size of the data you are encrypting so that you need to encode less data.  (Either that or don't put the data in url's in the first place e.g. store the data in a database and put a unique id in the url).  So compress > encrypt > encode.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to suggest. Store your data server side and pass a hash token like a sha1 hash identifying that record in your database. Then you're only dealing with 40 alphanumeric characters that don't need to be base64 encoded or urlencoded and you can reference the data by pulling it out of your own server easily, safely, and securely without exposing your encoded data to every site visitor asking hackers to try to break your encryption and corrupt your site.

Answer (score 1):

URL encoding will not significantly expand a base64 encoded string, since 62 of the 64 characters do not need to be modified. However, you can use [modified base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) to do a little better. This encoding uses the '-' and '_' characters in place of the '+' and '/' characters to yield a slight efficiency improvement.

The cipher itself is not causing any significant data expansion. It will pad the data to be a multiple of the block length, but that is insignificant in your case. You might try compressing the input prior to encryption. 256 bytes is not much but you might see some improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If your data structure is 256 bytes long encrypting it with a block cipher of 8 bytes increases it up to 8 bytes (depending of the concrete input length).

Therefore before applying base64 you have up to 264 bytes which are increased by the base64 encoding up to 352 bytes.

Therefore as you can see the most overhead is created by the base64 encoding. There are some slightly more effective encodings available like base91 - but they are very uncommon.

If size matters I would recommend to compress the data before encrypting it.